# How to understand どのメニューも工夫されたものばかりです

Tags: expressions, particle-に, particle-も, particle-ばかり

From chapter 25 of 新标准日本语中级, titled 創作中華料理コンテストの実現:

> 野田：おかげさまで、今回の創作中華料理コンテストには、全国から１００００件を超す応募がありました。創作カクテル部門にも１０００件以上の応募がありました。
> 大山：本当ですか。それはすごい。
> 野田：**どのメニューも工夫されたものばかりです**。

If どのメニュー takes the *ga* (nominative)-case, the meaning seems to be

> Every menu is just a devised thing.

which is weird to me.

If どのメニュー takes the *ni* (locative)-case (i.e. =どのメニューにも), it gets more understandable to me as

> On every menu there are all devised things.

Is this sentence in the latter case?

Comment: The menus are being devised, ie. created.  I'm not sure what you mean by "on every menu there are devised things".  That sounds strange.

Comment: @A.Ellett I mean, "on every menu there are devised things(=dishes)"

Comment: It might help to understand that メニュー does not mean "menu", it means "menu item". Probably a better word to translate it with is "dish".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing どの correlates with ばかり, which means *every single...*.

メニュー does take the nominative, but if you drop どの, then it should also drop ばかり and will be something like

- (この)メニューは工夫されたものです.

which means *this menu is a devised thing* or more understandably *this menu has an element of invention in it*. (Note there is not *just*).

The original sentence translates to *Every single menu has an invention in it*. Your sentence would render like どのメニューにも工夫があります, which basically means the same thing as the original.

Comment: Except that "Every single menu..." is a mistranslation, unless you think that "menu" can mean "an item on a menu".

Comment: @BrianChandler Yeah, I suppose it should be a dish as you commented to the OP. BTW to the English native speakers, *menu* is a list of foods? I think on the continent it often defaults to a (predefined) set of dishes (like Japanese 定食).